# Changing label in custom search form in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have created a custom search form and am using it within a block. I have selected a content type under the Content Selector area called Basic Content. I want to change that label to read Foo but not sure where to do. Any help would be appreciated. Using D7.

Comment: May I know how the custom search form was implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Structure - > Content Type - > Basic Page and select the field you are trying to edit - there should be options to change the name under the field management page . Let me know if that helps ..